# c# show textbox depending on sql value

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, if-statement, textbox

I have an winform app with 2 forms and a DB, in `form 1` the user selects from several `pictureboxes` after the selection is made `form2` opens and some `textboxes` and `labels` will appear according to the selection made in `form1`.
the problem is, that there is no way for the app to know what item was selected in `form1` to process the information from sql.
In the table there are 3 columns id, description and prumos.
how can i make the app recognize that i selected the picturebox with the id x, that corresponds to x number of "prumos" so that the app can display the correct textboxes?

the code i have thanks to your help already is:

```
    cc();
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select prumos from dbo.modelos";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        object value;
        try
        {
            value = dr["prumos"];
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) 
        {
            value = null;
        }
        string check = value != null ? value.ToString() : null;
        textBox13.Visible = (check == "2" || check == "3");
        textBox18.Visible = (check == "2" || check == "3");
        textBox17.Visible = (check == "2" || check == "3");
        textBox14.Visible = check == "3";
        textBox16.Visible = check == "3";
        textBox15.Visible = check == "3";
        label16.Visible = (check == "2" || check == "3");
        label20.Visible = check == "3";
    }
    else
    {

    }
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
    }
```

[image: example]

thanks very much for your help and time

Comment: Why do you have the same condition in `if` and `else if`?

Comment: i had to use it to check for the values 2 or 3.
if ir remove the line i get the error: The name 'check' does not exist in the current context But i may be wrong :\

Comment: What do you mean by if you use Read() the app won't access the database? Did you try while(dr.Read()){}?

Comment: I have some values loaded from the DB in that form, but if i use dr.read those values wont load. if i remove the line they appear but no textbox rules

Comment: Your else part will always throw an exception, if (dr.HasRows) fails,var check = dr["prumos"].ToString(); in the else part will throw exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just guessing, because there isn't much information in the question.
So what you really want to achieve is:
Fetch only the first row of some query and change the visibility of some controls *"depending on the value of a column"*?

Well if that's the case then it's easy:

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select prumos from dbo.modelos";
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(dr.Read())
{ 
    // if dr.Read() returns true we already know that dr.HasRows was also true
    object value = null;
    try
    {
        value = dr["prumos"];
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfRangeException) // thrown if there is no such column
    {
    }
    string check = value != null ? value.ToString() : null;
    textBox13.Visible = (check == "2" || check == "3");
    textBox18.Visible = (check == "2" || check == "3");
    textBox17.Visible = (check == "2" || check == "3");
    textBox14.Visible = check == "3";
    textBox16.Visible = check == "3";
    textBox15.Visible = check == "3";
    label16.Visible = (check == "2" || check == "3");
    label20.Visible = check == "3";
}
else 
{
   // what to do if there is no row?
}
dr.Close();
con.Close();
```

Comment: thanks for the help, 
in the line `string check = value != null : value.ToString() : null;`
I get the error _Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'_

Comment: Ok, now it accepst the code but the textboxes wont show no matter what model i select.
your code makes sense but nothing happens.

Comment: im sorry for the lack of information, i will try to explain editing my question. 
can you check it out please.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the problem is, that there is no way for the app to know what item was selected in form1 to process the information from sql"_ ?  Do you want to filter the data from the db, so that only the row with the id "x" is used for your "Processing code"? Why not use a filter at SQL level in the first place? E.g.: `"select prumos from dbo.modelos where id = " + x` for whatever x may be. It would also be wise to handle the case where no row is retrieved from the db (my last comment in code). If you fail to retrieve any data you wouldn't notice it, if you don't handle the case.

Comment: Sorry I missed the first point of this quotation. Do you want to say, that you don't know how to transfer data between objects?

Comment: Once again thanks for your help.
I uploaded a picture of the app, i hope it can make more sense.
its complicated to explain by text.
what i want is for the central columns info to be read from the sql table and the form to display the correct number of textboxes.

Comment: First you have to handover the selected window id to the 2nd form just before you show it. So you get something like `private void SelectionEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) { new form2(selectedWindowId).Show(); }` on `form1` and depending on where you use this information store it in the object or directly use it in the constructor for `form2`. For the case you use it in the constructor and selectedWindowId is an integer you can adjust your SQL query like I mentioned in my last comment (replace `x` with `selectedWindowId.ToString()`).

Comment: I also recommend to abstract away the db access code and instead use something like strongly typed DataSets. More information on this topic is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ok, so i used this code to handover the id in form1                 `build build = new build("@../Images/JAF.jpg", "1 Folha de Correr/Fixo", "c1");
                build.ShowDialog();` and in form2 i used:        
`public build(string img_from_A, string desc, string id)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox2.Load(img_from_A);
            desc1.Text = desc;
            id.ToString();`
i changed the query to              `cmd.CommandText = "select prumos from dbo.modelos where id = id";`
but i think the form2 code is missing something

Comment: Your line with the query should be `cmd.CommandText = "select prumos from dbo.modelos where id = '" + id + "'";` and `id.ToString();` is superfluous in this case. Be cautious with the **'** right before the 2nd quotation mark(**"**) and between the last two quotation marks.

Comment: i used your code, i got an error in the  `+ id +` and corrected it by adding `private string id;` in build. after this the app runs but all textboxes are displayed no matter what window i select :\

Comment: Another guess, you didn't construct the query in the `build` constructor and also didn't store the id from your parameter to your newly created private field `id`? Just add this line `this.id = id;` to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var check = dr["prumos"].ToString();
```

with

```
var check = dr[0].ToString();
```

I think that in your DataReader not exists the 'prumos' column, but a simple text 'Result not found'

Try it

Comment: Unfortunately still not working, what i cant figure out is why, when i apply this code the app stopps accessing the DB. if i comment this section the app can access the DB

Comment: I did not understand, if you write 'dr[0]' what value there is in 'check'?